# What should be the definition of a solution to a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We say thay $y$ is a solution to a differential equation $y{'}=f(y)$ if $y$ satisfy the equation. Why is this never stated to be if and only if? Since any solution should also satisfy the equation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the linguistic way we formulate definitions.

If we state

> **Definition.** A foo is called a bar if it has the gnaz property.

then the definition of the term 'bar' is intended to be understood so that

> **Theorem.** A foo is a bar if and only if it has the gnaz property.

holds.